# How to apply Word2Vec on SVM

Tags: svm, word2vec, train-test-split

I am not sure how to fit my `SVM model` with `Word2vec` training data set ?what should I put instead of `question mark` in below code?

```
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(sentences= df['meaningful_words'])

Train_X, Test_X, Train_Y, Test_Y = model_selection.train_test_split(df['y_labels'],df['meaningful_words'],random_state =1,test_size=0.2)

SVM = svm.SVC(C=1.0, kernel='linear', degree=1, gamma= 'auto')

SVM.fit(??,Train_Y)

predictions_SVM = SVM.predict(Test_X)

print("SVM Accuracy Score",accuracy_score(predictions_SVM, Test_Y)*100)
CONFUSION = confusion_matrix(Test_Y, predictions_SVM)
```

Comment: What is in `Train_X` and of what type?

Comment: I simply used sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split to split my whole data into random train and test subsets.So Train_X are those data selected randomly to be used as a training data  and rest as a test data( Test_X). Train_X type is pandas.core.series.